# Debounce Celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery

Is there a standard method for debouncing Celery tasks?

For example, so that a task can be "started" multiple times, but will only be run once after some delay:

```
def debounce_task(task):
    if task_is_queued(task):
        return
    task.apply_async(countdown=30)
```

Comment: You can use a cache. Many key-value stores have timed records, try to fetch the result from the store, if there is no result then run the task and store the result with an expiration time before returning. Use just one worker so tasks will execute sequentially. Avoid lock schemes unless you want to deal with stale locks.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. But I'd rather avoid the fiddly bits of implementing debouncing myself (checking arguments, tracking results, etc), and I'm wondering if there's any standard way of doing it.

Comment: It is dead simple to write a cache decorator in Python (may be 4 lines), I wish I had time to post a complete answer.

Comment: Definitely :) I'm sure a good coder come up with an 80% solution in an hour! But I'd like to know whether there's a more complete solution that already exists.

Comment: By any chance are you running celery on Redis instead of AMQP?

Comment: Technically this is throttling, not debouncing. But celery uses throttle in another way. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/ For it to be a true debounce each call of the task should reset the countdown. That is if I keep calling the task it won't run until I've stopped calling it for the duration of the timeout, each call resets the countdown.

Comment: To do a true debounce you can use a redis atomic counter. Each time you queue the task, incr the counter and start the countdown. When the task runs decr the counter. If the counter is 0 then run the task.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how we do it with Redis counters. All of this can probably be generalized in a decorator but we only use it for a specific task (webhooks)

Your public-facing task is what you call from other functions. It'll need to increment a key in Redis. The key is formed by the arguments of your function, whatever they may be (this ensures the counter is unique amongst individual tasks)

```
@task
def your_public_task(*args, **kwargs):
    cache_key = make_public_task_cache_key(*args, **kwargs)
    get_redis().incr(cache_key)
    _your_task(*args, **kwargs, countdown=settings.QUEUE_DELAY)
```

Note the cache key functions are shared (you want the same cache key in each function), and the `countdown` setting.

Then, the actual task executing the code does the following:

```
@task
def _your_task(*args, **kwargs):
    cache_key = make_public_task_cache_key(*args, **kwargs)
    counter = get_redis().getset(cache_key, 0)
    # redis makes the zero a string.
    if counter == '0':
       return

    ... execute your actual task code.
```

This lets you hit `your_public_task.delay(..)` as many times as you want, within your `QUEUE_DELAY`, and it'll only fire off once.

Comment: Interesting algorithm, but to my mind, debouncing is for a situation where you might get a burst of requests, and you want to wait until they're exhausted before running the task. This won't wait until they're exhausted, as it will always fire `QUEUE_DELAY` seconds after the *first* request, not the last.

Answer (score 4):

bartek has the idea, use redis counters which are atomic (and should be easily available if your broker is redis). Although his solution is thottling, not debouncing. The difference is minor though (getset vs decr).

Queue up the task:

```
conn = get_redis()
conn.incr(key)
task.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, countdown=countdown)
```

Then in the task:

```
conn = get_redis()
counter = conn.decr(key)
if counter > 0:
    # task is still queued
    return
# continue on to rest of task
```

It's hard to make it a decorator since you need to decorate the task and calling the task itself. So you will need a decorator before the celery @task decorator and one after it.

For now I'm just made some functions that help me call the task, and one that checks in the start of the task.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43625455/4391298 is a solution I finally got to, including some key expiry to handle it melting down (not a problem in the original solution).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with Mongo.

NOTE: I had to make the design a little more forgiving, as Celery tasks aren't guaranteed to execute the exact moment of `eta` is met or `countdown` runs out.

Also, Mongo expiring indexes are only cleaned up every minute or so; So you can't base the design around records being deleted the moment the `eta` is up.

Anyhow, the flow is something like this:

1. Client code calls `my_task`.
2. `preflight` increments a call counter, and returns it as `flight_id`
3. `_my_task` is set to be executed after `TTL` seconds.
4. When `_my_task` runs, it checks if it's `flight_id` is still current. If it's not, it aborts.
5. ... sometime later... mongo cleans up stale entries in the collection, [via an expiring index.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

---

```
@celery.task(track_started=False, ignore_result=True)
def my_task(my_arg):
    flight_id = preflight(inflight_collection, 'my_task', HASH(my_arg), TTL)
    _my_task.apply_async((my_arg,), {'flight_id':flight_id}, countdown=TTL)

@celery.task(track_started=False, ignore_result=True)
def _my_task(my_arg, flight_id=None):
    if not check_for_takeoff(inflight_collection, 'my_task', HASH(my_arg), flight_id):
        return
    # ... actual work ... #
```

---

Library code:

```
TTL = 5 * 60     # Run tasks after 5 minutes
EXPIRY = 6 * TTL # This needs to be much larger than TTL. 

# We need to store a list of task-executions currently pending
inflight_collection = db['celery_In_Flight']
inflight_collection.create_index([('fn', pymongo.ASCENDING,),
                                  ('key', pymongo.ASCENDING,)])
inflight_collection.create_index('eta', expiresAfterSeconds=EXPIRY)


def preflight(collection, fn, key, ttl):
    eta = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=ttl)
    result = collection.find_one_and_update({
        'fn': fn,
        'key': key,
    }, {
        '$set': {
            'eta': eta
        },
        '$inc': {
            'flightId': 1
        }
    }, upsert=True, return_document=pymongo.ReturnDocument.AFTER)
    print 'Preflight[{}][{}] = {}'.format(fn, key, result['flightId'])
    return result['flightId']


def check_for_takeoff(collection, fn, key, flight_id):
    result = collection.find_one({
        'fn': fn,
        'key': key
    })
    ready = result is None or result['flightId'] == flight_id
    print 'Check[{}][{}] = {}, {}'.format(fn, key, result['flightId'], ready)
    return ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with: https://gist.github.com/wolever/3cf2305613052f3810a271e09d42e35c

And copied here, for posterity:

```
import time

import redis


def get_redis_connection():
    return redis.connect()

class TaskDebouncer(object):
    """ A simple Celery task debouncer.

        Usage::

            def debounce_process_corpus(corpus):
                # Only one task with ``key`` will be allowed to execute at a
                # time. For example, if the task was resizing an image, the key
                # might be the image's URL.
                key = "process_corpus:%s" %(corpus.id, )
                TaskDebouncer.delay(
                    key, my_taks, args=[corpus.id], countdown=0,
                )

            @task(bind=True)
            def process_corpus(self, corpus_id, debounce_key=None):
                debounce = TaskDebouncer(debounce_key, keepalive=30)

                corpus = Corpus.load(corpus_id)

                try:
                    for item in corpus:
                        item.process()

                        # If ``debounce.keepalive()`` isn't called every
                        # ``keepalive`` interval (the ``keepalive=30`` in the
                        # call to ``TaskDebouncer(...)``) the task will be
                        # considered dead and another one will be allowed to
                        # start.
                        debounce.keepalive()

                finally:
                    # ``finalize()`` will mark the task as complete and allow
                    # subsequent tasks to execute. If it returns true, there
                    # was another attempt to start a task with the same key
                    # while this task was running. Depending on your business
                    # logic, this might indicate that the task should be
                    # retried.
                    needs_retry = debounce.finalize()

                if needs_retry:
                    raise self.retry(max_retries=None)

    """

    def __init__(self, key, keepalive=60):
        if key:
            self.key = key.partition("!")[0]
            self.run_key = key
        else:
            self.key = None
            self.run_key = None
        self._keepalive = keepalive
        self.cxn = get_redis_connection()
        self.init()
        self.keepalive()

    @classmethod
    def delay(cls, key, task, args=None, kwargs=None, countdown=30):
        cxn = get_redis_connection()
        now = int(time.time())
        first = cxn.set(key, now, nx=True, ex=countdown + 10)
        if not first:
            now = cxn.get(key)

        run_key = "%s!%s" %(key, now)
        if first:
            kwargs = dict(kwargs or {})
            kwargs["debounce_key"] = run_key
            task.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, countdown=countdown)

        return (first, run_key)

    def init(self):
        self.initial = self.key and self.cxn.get(self.key)

    def keepalive(self, expire=None):
        if self.key is None:
            return
        expire = expire if expire is not None else self._keepalive
        self.cxn.expire(self.key, expire)

    def is_out_of_date(self):
        if self.key is None:
            return False
        return self.cxn.get(self.key) != self.initial

    def finalize(self):
        if self.key is None:
            return False
        with self.cxn.pipeline() as pipe:
            while True:
                try:
                    pipe.watch(self.key)
                    if pipe.get(self.key) != self.initial:
                        return True
                    pipe.multi()
                    pipe.delete(self.key)
                    pipe.execute()
                    break
                except redis.WatchError:
                    continue
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more filled out solution based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/28157498/4391298 but turned into a decorator and reaching into the Kombu connection pool to reuse your Redis counter.

```
import logging
from functools import wraps

# Not strictly required
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

from celery.utils import gen_task_name


LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def debounced_task(**options):
    """Debounced task decorator."""

    try:
        countdown = options.pop('countdown')
    except KeyError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Debounced tasks require a countdown")

    def factory(func):
        """Decorator factory."""
        try:
            name = options.pop('name')
        except KeyError:
            name = gen_task_name(app, func.__name__, func.__module__)

        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            """Decorated function."""

            key = make_template_fragment_key(name, [args, kwargs])
            with app.pool.acquire_channel(block=True) as (_, channel):
                depth = channel.client.decr(key)

                if depth <= 0:
                    try:
                        func(*args, **kwargs)
                    except:
                        # The task failed (or is going to retry), set the
                        # count back to where it was
                        channel.client.set(key, depth)
                        raise
                else:
                    LOGGER.debug("%s calls pending to %s",
                                depth, name)

        task = app._task_from_fun(inner, **options, name=name + '__debounced')

        @wraps(func)
        def debouncer(*args, **kwargs):
            """
            Debouncer that calls the real task.
            This is the task we are scheduling."""

            key = make_template_fragment_key(name, [args, kwargs])
            with app.pool.acquire_channel(block=True) as (_, channel):
                # Mark this key to expire after the countdown, in case our
                # task never runs or runs too many times, we want to clean
                # up our Redis to eventually resolve the issue.
                channel.client.expire(key, countdown + 10)
                depth = channel.client.incr(key)

            LOGGER.debug("Requesting %s in %i seconds (depth=%s)",
                         name, countdown, depth)
            task.si(*args, **kwargs).apply_async(countdown=countdown)

        return app._task_from_fun(debouncer, **options, name=name)

    return factory
```